# Sound Professionals SP-BMC-1 recordings

Tags: binaural, field-recording

Hey all.

Just thought I'd post a quick recording I made of me making soup/toast/coffee/washing hands,etc in my kitchen with my new SP-BMC2 binaural (edit:just realised on the packaging they're the BMC2 not the BMC1!) mics that I got recently (cheers for the heads up guys!). Quite a noisy, hissy gas hob unfortunately though :/ Sounds of me eating/drinking at the end of it!

http://soundcloud.com/andrewjohnlewis/sets/binuaral-sound-recording

Download original with link at 48/24.

How many other got their hands on them during the special offer? Mine didn't come with any windscreens so any sudden head movements/walking can be slightly noticeable, but I'm quite happy with the sound. Will need to somehow find some mini windjammers suitable if I ever take them outdoors. Will no doubt get strange looks with my excessive ear hair growth if I did! lol

*Just be careful*, levels are bit peaky! Wanted to demonstrate the dynamic range of the mics a bit though. Recorded into an H2 with plug-in power on. (some noise reduction carried out after)

Obviously best listened on headphones! (but not too loud)

Anyone else bought these mics and wanna share put up some sounds? :)
Enjoy
Andy

Comment: I didn't get any, the recording I heard hurt my ears!


Comment: Sorry dude, those plates are a bit clanky I know! Best not listen to too loudly as I mentioned ;)

Comment: It's not your recording that hurts my ears it's the quality of the microphone.

Comment: I didnt think the mics were sooo bad, bearing in mind I only paid $10 for them lol

Comment: Screechy digital distortion from them put me off and was the only reason I didn't order (they are $70) off sale.